# Reading elements in List to render Card Widgets in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi guys so as the title suggests, i am trying to read elements from a final List with 6 elements to render Cards that have text that represents the elements in the lists

`itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>  Card(child: Center(child: Text('Random Text')),`

below is the list im trying to read

`final listOfClusters = ['HEART', 'VOICE', 'MOVE', 'MIND', 'FORCE', 'STRIKE'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in a `ListView` :

```
itemCount: listOfClusters.length,
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>  
    Card(child: Center(child: Text(listOfClusters[index])),
```

in a children list :

```
children: [
    for(var cluster in listOfClusters)
        Card(child: Center(child: Text(cluster)),
]
```

Comment: Thanks! is there anyway that i can change the card size? i tried wrapping it with Container and setting its width / height like how i usually do but it seems that its not working with itemBuilder

Comment: The items width are bound to the `ListView` width. You can wrap the `Card` with an `Align` to override that.